# How to append an entire array to a string in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to recreate a program I made with C++ into a C# windows form program I have the bulk of it done. There's one small thing that's keeping the program from working like it should.

My program is a bionformatics program that allows the user to either enter a string/sequence of DNA or RNA characters and the program converts it into the corresponding protein/amino acid and prints out an amino acid/protein for every codon the program sees. So if I input "AAA GGG CCC" it prints out "Lysine Glycine Proline".

This is the snippet of code I'm having trouble with in the C++ version

```
for (i=0; i<numberOfCodons;i++)
{
    endIndex=beginIndex+3;
    codon="";
    {
        //here is where I'm having the trouble converting this to C# and have it cout the write
        //way                  
        codon.append(RNA.substr(beginIndex,endIndex-beginIndex));
    }
    for (k=0;k<64;k++)
    {
        if(codon==codons[k])
        {
             //here is where I'm having the trouble converting this to C# and have it cout the write way
             //like I metioned previously AAA GGG CCC couts Lysine Glycine Proline 
             protein.append(aminoAcids[k]);                
        }            
    }
    beginIndex+=3;
}
cout<<protein<<endl;
protein.clear();
```

here's what I have in c# so far

```
private void Tranlate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    numberOfCodons = rnaLength / 3;
    beginIndex = 0;
    richTextBox2.AppendText("Total Number Of codons are: ");
    richTextBox2.AppendText(numberOfCodons.ToString());
    richTextBox2.AppendText("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfCodons; i++)
    {
        endIndex = beginIndex + 3;
        codon = "";                
        {
            // these are the two possible conversions of the C++ code that dont work at all for me******
            // codon.AppendText(RNA.Substring(beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex));
            codon=(RNA.Substring(beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex));
        }
        for (k = 0; k < 64; k++)
        {
            if (codon == codons[k])
            {
                //supposed to print out all the coresponding amino acids from the array and it will only print out one amino acid (Lysine)*******
                //protein.AppendText(aminoAcids[k]);
                protein = (aminoAcids[k]);
            }
        }
        beginIndex += 3;
    }
    richTextBox2.AppendText(protein);
    richTextBox2.AppendText("\n");
    //protein.clear();
}
```

Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this line inside your loop

```
protein = (aminoAcids[k]);
```

to

```
protein += (aminoAcids[k]);
```

The C++ version loops for 64 times and append to a string, the C# version reinitialize the string every time and ends with the last match found by the comparison  `if (codon == codons[k])`.

The same happens with the codon string
This reinitialize it in every loop

```
codon=(RNA.Substring(beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex));
```

but, in this case, I'm not sure if it is right to build a single string and then check against a string array like `codons[k]`

PS. While they are ininfluent on the code generated, I find your liberal use of parenthesys a bit distracting. You could write `aminoAcids[k];` and `codon=RNA.Substring(beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex);`. This is (in my opinion) more clear.

Comment: Also, consider using StringBuilder

Comment: @GiladNaaman, not sure if, in this case, the usage of StringBuilder is really effective. See here http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-performance .

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a nice candidate for LINQ which is widely used in C#. If I understood the logic correctly, you could write something like:

```
richTextBox2.AppendText(string.Join("\n",
                                      Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfCodons)
                                        .Select(i => RNA.Substring(i * 3, i * 3 + 3))
                                        .Where(c => codons.Contains(c))
                                        .Select(c => aminoAcids[codons.IndexOf(c)])
                                        .ToArray())
                                    );
```